# Disabling keyboard input for input element of type="number" while allowing steps

Tags: reactjs

I am making a custom **number input** component in React that is either typeable or not depending on whether the prop typeable is defined. And if it is 'untypeable', I still want the arrows to be accessible for stepping. In other words, for an untypeable number input component, I want to restrict the user to only use the arrows. However, I can not find a way to make it work. I am aware that in HTML I can do `<input type="number" min="0" max="10" step="1"  onkeydown="return false" />` but I cannot figure out the equivalent in React.
I tried returning `<input type="number" onKeyDown={()=>false} />` but to no avail. How can I do the similar thing in react?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer, doing `<input type="number" onKeyDown={(e)=>e.preventDefault()} />` worked for me.